# Problem with Instagram Basic Display API: "reduce the amount of data"

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-basic

Last 10 hours I have a problem "Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request" with reauest to API Instagram Basic Display.
Or nothing is returned at all during the timeout.

In the developer panel, basic-display-rate-limiting shows that 100% of calls are available, meaning the limit has not been exceeded.

I paused the requests for some time. I changed a server. It didn't help.
The bag report in FB is doesn't works.
Don't know what to do.